# How to make a field dropdown with value in Dynamic Row magento 2 Admin

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form, dynamic-rows

I just created a dynamicRow using UIform (UiComponent). In this the value field I want to make it drop-down with predefined values. How to make it a drop-down, also I want to change another field's datatype:textarea.

[image: **Dynamic Row Magento 2**]

My form.xml:

```
<dynamicRows name="Sample" sortOrder="50" >
        <settings>
            <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Value</addButtonLabel>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="admin__field-wide">false</class>
            </additionalClasses>
            <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
            <dndConfig>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
            </dndConfig>
        </settings>
        <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.row</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="name" formElement="input">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                        <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">NAME</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="value" formElement="input">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">value</item>
                        <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">value</item>
                        <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">VALUE</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <actionDelete name="action_delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                        <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">Params.delete</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <componentType>actionDelete</componentType>
                </settings>
            </actionDelete>
        </container>
    </dynamicRows>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your snippet and changing a few fields does work at my end.

```
 <dynamicRows name="Sample" sortOrder="50" >
                <settings>
                    <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Value</addButtonLabel>
                    <additionalClasses>
                        <class name="admin__field-wide">false</class>
                    </additionalClasses>
                    <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
                    <dndConfig>
                        <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                    </dndConfig>
                </settings>
                <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record</item>
                            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.row</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <field name="name" formElement="input">
                        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                                <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">NAME</item>
                                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </field>
                    <field name="value" formElement="select">
                        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">value</item>
                                <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">value</item>
                                <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">VALUE</item>
                                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                        <formElements>
                            <select>
                                <settings>
                                    <options class="Mbs\AdminScreen\Ui\Component\CartLog\Localisation\Options"/>
                                </settings>
                            </select>
                        </formElements>
                    </field>
                    <actionDelete name="action_delete">
                        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                                <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">Params.delete</item>
                                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                        <settings>
                            <dataType>text</dataType>
                            <componentType>actionDelete</componentType>
                        </settings>
                    </actionDelete>
                </container>
            </dynamicRows>
```

And the options class:

```
class Options implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => '', 'label' => __('None')],
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('one')],
            ['value' => 2, 'label' => __('two')]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way we can limit the dynamic rows to maximum 10? @herve can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

**Add into your ui-form xml**

```
<fieldset name="label_setting">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Dynamic Rows</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="discount_row">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows</item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_ModuleName/dynamic-rows/grid</item>
                <!-- change Template file -->
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">dynamicRows</item>
                <item name="recordTemplate" xsi:type="string">record</item>
                <item name="deleteButtonLabel" xsi:type="string">Remove</item>
                <item name="addButtonLabel" xsi:type="string">Add New</item>
                <item name="deleteProperty" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <!-- <item name="dndConfig" xsi:type="array">
<item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item> -->
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="record">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record</item>
                    <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="field_name1">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\DiscountNumbers</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Field #1</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">field_name1</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">field_name1</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="field_name2">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Field #2</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">field_name2</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">field_name2</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <actionDelete>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Actions</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">130</item>
                        <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">data-grid-actions-cell</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </actionDelete>
        </container>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

> **Add drop down option** *VendoreName\ModuleName\Model* *DiscountNumbers.php*

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class DiscountNumbers implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $options['0'] = __('1% - 10%');
        $options['1'] = __('11% - 20%');
        $options['2'] = __('21% - 30%');
        $options['3'] = __('31% - 40%');
        $options['4'] = __('41% - 50%');
        $options['5'] = __('51% - 60%');
        $options['6'] = __('61% - 70%');
        $options['7'] = __('71% - 80%');
        $options['8'] = __('81% - 90%');
        $options['9'] = __('91% - 100%');
        return $options;
    }



    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $res = $this->getOptions();
        array_unshift($res, ['value' => '', 'label' => '']);
        return $res; 
    } 

    public function getOptions() 
    { 
        $res = []; 
        foreach ($this->getOptionArray() as $index => $value) 
        { 
            $res[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value]; 
        } 
        return $res; 
    }
    public function toOptionArray() 
    { 
        return $this->getOptions(); 
    } 
 }
```

> **add this template file**
> *VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/template/dynamic-rows*
> *grid.html*

```
<div class="admin__field-complex" if="$data.addButton">
    <div class="admin__field-complex-title">
        <span class="label" translate="'Add Your Title'"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="admin__field-complex-elements">
        <render args="fallbackResetTpl" if="$data.showFallbackReset && $data.isDifferedFromDefault" />
        <button attr="{disabled: disabled}" class="action-secondary" type="button" click="processingAddChild.bind($data, false, false, false)">
            <span translate="addButtonLabel" />
        </button>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="admin__field admin__field-wide" visible="visible" disabled="disabled" css="$data.setClasses($data)" attr="'data-index': index">
    <label if="$data.label" class="admin__field-label" attr="for: $data.uid">
        <span translate="$data.label" />
    </label>

    <div class="admin__field-control" data-role="grid-wrapper">
        <div class="admin__control-table-pagination" visible="!!element.getRecordCount()">
            <div class="admin__data-grid-pager">
                <button class="action-previous" type="button" data-bind="attr: {title: $t('Previous Page')}, click: previousPage, disable: isFirst()"></button>
                <input class="admin__control-text" type="number" data-bind="attr: {id: ++ko.uid}, value: currentPage" />
                <label class="admin__control-support-text" data-bind="attr: {for: ko.uid}, text: 'of ' + pages()"></label>
                <button class="action-next" type="button" data-bind="attr: {title: $t('Next Page')}, click: nextPage, disable: isLast()"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="admin__control-table-wrapper">
            <table class="admin__dynamic-rows data-grid" data-role="grid">
                <thead if="element.columnsHeader">
                    <tr>
                        <th if="$data.dndConfig.enabled" class="data-grid-draggable-row-cell" />

                        <th repeat="foreach: labels, item: '$label'" class="data-grid-th" visible="$label().visible" disable="$label().disabled" css="setClasses($label())">
                            <span translate="$label().label" />
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr repeat="foreach: elems, item: '$record'" class="data-row" css="'_odd-row': $index % 2">
                        <td if="dndConfig.enabled" class="data-grid-draggable-row-cell" template="name: dndConfig.template, data: dnd" />

                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: $record().elems(), as: 'elem'} -->
                        <td if="elem.template" visible="elem.visible() && elem.formElement !== 'hidden'" disable="elem.disabled" css="$parent.setClasses(elem)" template="elem.template" attr="'data-index': index" />
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I Hope This Helps You.**

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :- 1**

```
<field name="details_page_specification_template">
                        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">                       
                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Old</item>
                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">New</item>
                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Specification Template</item>
                                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">details_page_specification_template</item>
                                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </field>
```

**Solution :- 2**

```
<field name="restrict_from_guest">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\DiscountNumbers</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Restrict from Guests (Users who are not logged in)</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">restrict_from_guest</item>
                        
                        <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
```