# How to create Dynamic rows in custom admin form?

Tags: admin, magento2.3, forms

I want to create a form field which has dynamic rows in that page.
Also, I want to store the form data in database table.
I already referred this link >> https://github.com/bbakalovGlobal/Bss_DynamicRows 
Anyone has any demo extension for that

Comment: did you get the answer??

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/323568/82670

Comment: You can refer this link this is good example. https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/components/dynamic-rows/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link to add a dynamic row in the custom admin form and let me know if it works for you or not.

https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-html-content-with-dynamic-rows-in-magento2/